# Using app from Apache in Tomcat application

Tags: apache, rest, tomcat

Basically I have 2 RESTful services: one build in Java and using Tomcat server, and other build in PHP and using Apache Server.
Is there any way to configure such that the app from Tomcat becomes a consumer of the one from Apache?

The webservice from Tomcat is at address:

```
http://localhost:8080/myapp1
```

and the app from Apache is at address:

```
http://localhost:80/myapp2.
```

What I want is to use the responses of the RESTful service on Apache in the Tomcat one, something like this to use from the Java code:

```
HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet(http://localhost:80/myapp2/items);
```

Currently I am receiving 404-Not Found. Is there any way to do this? Or is there another way to make the services communicate?

Comment: Is Apache httpd configured to serve a VirtualHost only under a specific hostname? Is your PHP-based RESTful app configured to run under the default VirtualHost?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Forgot to post the answer. I feel so dumb - I was having a mistake in my code. It works as expected. Here is a simple example of calling the Apache server from Tomcat:

```
final static String BASE_URL = "http://localhost:80/proiect/";

    private String getResponse(String title) {
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        String url = (title != null && title.length() > 0) ? BASE_URL + "?title=" + title : BASE_URL;
        HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet(url);
        String response;
        try {
            ResponseHandler<String> responseHandler = new BasicResponseHandler();
            response = httpclient.execute(httpget, responseHandler);
            return response;

        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }
```